Database queries buffer
I have the following requirement to fulfill:
When the database is unavailable, I have to write all queries into a buffer file (for ex. .PMQ) for later execution.
Caching database results is common knowledge for me, but I's first time when I approached storing "queries to execute" into separate file when database doesn't respond.
So I want to ask if there is any common design pattern or ready to implement solution for this case, how to handle this case correctly, and how to integrate it with for example. Entity Framework 8?

What form do the queries take?  Are you passing in SQL statements or passing parameters to stored procs?

You might be able to adapt a generic caching design pattern.  Most of these patterns (see links below) assume you want to read or write data - for example: grab a cached value if it's present in the cache instead of making a more expensive call to the database.
I'll use the word "cache" below, but in some cases a queue might also work.
I'm assuming all the queries are working asynchronously, and that you already have a way of passing the results back to the caller.
I have no experience with Entity Framework specifically.
So in terms of pattern you could:

Write all requests to a cache; then perform query; if successful, remove from cache.  When database "comes back", start executing the oldest queries in the cache first.
Attempt query; if fails write it to the cache.  When database "comes back", start executing cached queries.

Info on common caching patterns:

https://www.gomomento.com/blog/6-common-caching-design-patterns-to-execute-your-caching-strategy/
https://hazelcast.com/blog/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-caching-patterns/

